# How to use native op in pytorch

Tags: returnn

I want to use FastBaumWelchOp in pytorch

I try
python3 tools/compile_native_op.py --native_op FastBaumWelchOp
in python3

```
torch.ops.load_library('/var/tmp/root/returnn_tf_cache/ops/FastBaumWelchOp/a0e331db13/FastBaumWelchOp.so')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/_ops.py", line 104, in load_library
    ctypes.CDLL(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libopenblasp-r0-085ca80a.3.9.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```